# tuning PHP Zend Optimizer+

Tags: zend-server, zend-optimizer

I am looking to tune Zend Optimizer+ on our Zend Server installation. Is there any tool that can show statistics about Zend Optimizer's performance? e.g. number of hits and misses, utilization of shared memory etc.

Apart from Optimizer+ configuration directives, anything else we can do within our application code to help the bytecode caching engine do a better job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may call function accelerator_get_status() and see the result - it would contain some information about the O+ internal state and what happens inside.

You may also look into increasing realpath_cache_size - default is too small for big application.

Comment: accelerator_get_status() produces a very detailed report. Just what we wanted. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is not much to tune with Zend Optimizer. Check out:

- [Zend Optimizer User Guide (pdf)](http://www.zend.com/topics/Zend-Optimizer-User-Guide-043010.pdf)
- [Zend Optimizer Knowledge Base](http://kb.zend.com/index.php?CategoryID=65)

Apart from this, you can only tweak what is available through the Zend Server UI.

For Zend Optimizer Plus, there is a number of ini configs you can change as explained in

- http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/zendoptimizerplus.html